# assigning undefined class variable outside of the class!! - php

Tags: php, class, oop, variables

I don't understand this.

I have an empty class, and I can define a variable belonging to the class and assign values to it outside of the class!!
how is it possible?

```
<?php

class Test{}

$test = new Test();

var_dump(isset($test->foo));
$test->foo = 'bar';
var_dump(isset($test->foo));

echo $test->foo;
```

The result is as follows:

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
bar
```

someone pleases explain it. is it even safe that php has such a feature?

Comment: The [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) covers this (look at "Dynamic properties" section in the end). _"is it even safe that php has such a feature?"_ - What do you mean by "safe"? It can make it harder to debug (in case of typos etc), but I don't see it what it has to do with safety?

Comment: yes, I meant debugging-wise and developing-wise.

Comment: If you're afraid it would cause issues, then (before PHP 8.2), you can simply implement the magic method [__set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) that simply throws an exception if it's called. I've worked with PHP for many years and can't say that I've ever had an issue with it though. Nor have I heard others mentioning it either. Any decent IDE can be configured to notify you if you're using undefined properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in PHP < 8.2 it was allowed to dynamically assign properties to a class, in PHP 8.2 it will be depricated
https://stitcher.io/blog/deprecated-dynamic-properties-in-php-82